# Firebase Twitter Login : Unable to determine the authorization endpoint for the specified provider

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, twitter

I am facing a issue in Social Login Using Twitter with the use of Firebase database.

**Error** : **"Unable to determine the authorization endpoint for the specified provider. This may be an issue in the provider configuration"**

Below is the code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Twitter Authentication with Popup</title>

  <!-- Material Design Theming -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.orange-indigo.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

  <!-- Import and configure the Firebase SDK -->
  <!-- These scripts are made available when the app is served or deployed on Firebase Hosting -->
  <!-- If you do not serve/host your project using Firebase Hosting see https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup -->
  <script src="/__/firebase/5.0.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="/__/firebase/5.0.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>

  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.4/firebase.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.4/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.4/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    /**
     * Function called when clicking the Login/Logout button.
     */
    // [START buttoncallback]
    function toggleSignIn() {
      if (!firebase.auth().currentUser) {
        // [START createprovider]
        var provider = new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider();
        // [END createprovider]
        // [START signin]
        firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
          // This gives you a the Twitter OAuth 1.0 Access Token and Secret.
          // You can use these server side with your app's credentials to access the Twitter API.
          var token = result.credential.accessToken;
          var secret = result.credential.secret;
          // The signed-in user info.
          var user = result.user;
          // [START_EXCLUDE]
          document.getElementById('quickstart-oauthtoken').textContent = token;
          document.getElementById('quickstart-oauthsecret').textContent = secret;
          // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }).catch(function(error) {
          // Handle Errors here.
          var errorCode = error.code;
          var errorMessage = error.message;
          // The email of the user's account used.
          var email = error.email;
          // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
          var credential = error.credential;
          // [START_EXCLUDE]
          if (errorCode === 'auth/account-exists-with-different-credential') {
            alert('You have already signed up with a different auth provider for that email.');
            // If you are using multiple auth providers on your app you should handle linking
            // the user's accounts here.
          } else {
            console.error(error);
          }
          // [END_EXCLUDE]
        });
        // [END signin]
      } else {
        // [START signout]
        firebase.auth().signOut();
        // [END signout]
      }
      // [START_EXCLUDE]
      document.getElementById('quickstart-sign-in').disabled = true;
      // [END_EXCLUDE]
    }
    // [END buttoncallback]


    /**
     * initApp handles setting up UI event listeners and registering Firebase auth listener:
     *  - firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged: This listener is called when the user is signed in or
     *    out, and that is where we update the UI.
     */
    function initApp() {
      // Listening for auth state changes.
      // [START authstatelistener]
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
          // User is signed in.
          var displayName = user.displayName;
          var email = user.email;
          var emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
          var photoURL = user.photoURL;
          var isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous;
          var uid = user.uid;
          var providerData = user.providerData;
          // [START_EXCLUDE]
          document.getElementById('quickstart-sign-in-status').textContent = 'Signed in';
          document.getElementById('quickstart-sign-in').textContent = 'Sign out';
          document.getElementById('quickstart-account-details').textContent = JSON.stringify(user, null, '  ');
          // [END_EXCLUDE]
        } else {
          // User is signed out.
          // [START_EXCLUDE]
          document.getElementById('quickstart-sign-in-status').textContent = 'Signed out';
          document.getElementById('quickstart-sign-in').textContent = 'Sign in with Twitter';
          document.getElementById('quickstart-account-details').textContent = 'null';
          document.getElementById('quickstart-oauthtoken').textContent = 'null';
          document.getElementById('quickstart-oauthsecret').textContent = 'null';
          // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        document.getElementById('quickstart-sign-in').disabled = false;
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
      });
      // [END authstatelistener]

      document.getElementById('quickstart-sign-in').addEventListener('click', toggleSignIn, false);
    }

    window.onload = function() {
    var config = {
        apiKey: "",
        authDomain: "",
        databaseURL: "",
        projectId: "",
        storageBucket: "",
        messagingSenderId: ""
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
      initApp();
    };
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="demo-layout mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">

  <!-- Header section containing title -->
  <header class="mdl-layout__header mdl-color-text--white mdl-color--light-blue-700">
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-cell--12-col-tablet mdl-grid">
      <div class="mdl-layout__header-row mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-cell--12-col-tablet mdl-cell--8-col-desktop">
        <a href="/"><h3>Firebase Authentication</h3></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <main class="mdl-layout__content mdl-color--grey-100">
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-cell--12-col-tablet mdl-grid">

      <!-- Container for the demo -->
      <div class="mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col mdl-cell--12-col-tablet mdl-cell--12-col-desktop">
        <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-color--light-blue-600 mdl-color-text--white">
          <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">Twitter Authentication with Popup</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text mdl-color-text--grey-600">
          <p>Sign in with your Twitter account below.</p>

          <!-- Button that handles sign-in/sign-out -->
          <button disabled class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised" id="quickstart-sign-in">Sign in with Twitter</button>

          <!-- Container where we'll display the user details -->
          <div class="quickstart-user-details-container">
            Firebase sign-in status: <span id="quickstart-sign-in-status">Unknown</span>
            <div>Firebase auth <code>currentUser</code> object value:</div>
            <pre><code id="quickstart-account-details">null</code></pre>
            <div>Twitter OAuth Token:</div>
            <pre><code id="quickstart-oauthtoken">null</code></pre>
            <div>Twitter OAuth Secret:</div>
            <pre><code id="quickstart-oauthsecret">null</code></pre>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please fill the below details in the above code (Details will be in Firebase Web Setup) :

```
var config = {
            apiKey: "",
            authDomain: "",
            databaseURL: "",
            projectId: "",
            storageBucket: "",
            messagingSenderId: ""
          };
```

In the Above HTML if I click on Sign in with Twitter, it opens the popup and in response I am getting the error.

Please somebody help here to resolve the issue.

Thanks in advance.